# Error code 0x80070002 when trying to install IIS on Windows 10 Pro 64

Tags: windows, iis

I am trying to install IIS on my Windows 10 machine, but keep getting this error:

```
Windows couldn't complete the requested changes.

The system could not find the file specified.

Error code 0x80070002
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apply all pending Windows update and try again.

Comment: There are none, I always keep my PC up to date.

Comment: Then you don't have much more options, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues

Answer (score 0):

I think this error may be caused by the .net framework, you can try to run the following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -r
```

Or you can run one of the repair utilities supplied by Microsoft:

[Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

If you do not have the correct framework, you can download version at the following links:

[Download .NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework)

Once installed, try to install the IIS features again.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I have updated my post with more information.

Comment: Try running SFC/DISM to scans the integrity of all protected system files and replaces incorrect versions with.